# deleting words from a string with for

Tags: python, loops

I am triying to remove from a list, all words that contains "@"

```
string = "@THISISREMOVED @test2 @test3 @test4 a comment"
splitted = string.split()

for x in splitted:
    if '@' in x:
        splitted.remove(x)

string =' '.join(splitted)
print(string)
```

And it returns:

```
@test2 @test4 a comment
```

I want to delete ALL words that contains '@' not just the first one, how i can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove from a list, or do you want to remove from a string?

Comment: i recieve a string, so.. from a list

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Don't try to remove unwanted items from a list that you're looping over. Instead, build a new list that contains the words you want to keep.

Comment: I recieve a string from a server, so i converted the string into a list because It is the easiest way that i found  for remove a word.

Comment: There's some good information and various useful techniques at [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/4014959).

Comment: `" ".join([w for w in string.split(" ") if "@" not in w])` is the simplest approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove values from list while you are iterating over it.

```
string = "@THISISREMOVED @test2 @test3 @test4 a comment"
splitted = string.split()

result = []

for x in splitted:
    if '@' not in x:
        result.append(x)



string =' '.join(result)
print(string)

>>> a comment
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works !

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression module has a direct way of doing this:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('\w*@\w*')
>>> r.sub('',  "@THISISREMOVED @test2 @test3 @test4 a comment")
'    a comment'
```

To break down the regular expression:

```
r = re.compile('''
               \w* # zero or more characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _
               @   # an @ character
               \w* # zero or more characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _
               ''',
               re.VERBOSE)
```